# Like VLOOKUP, but with more

Tags: microsoft-excel

So, I have a list of patients. And then I have a list of sales orders that correspond to clinical visits they needed to receive. I'm wanting to see who was seen and who was not.

So, on sheet 1 I have a list of patients and their ID numbers (Patient ID is unique):
Patient ID, Patient Name

Then on sheet 2 I have a list of sales orders (Sales Order ID is unique, Patient ID is not):
Patient ID, Sales Order ID, Date of the Sales Order

What I want to do is have Excel look at the sales orders in sheet 2, find where the Patient ID matches, and then bring over the dates in sequence.

So, Sheet 1 would look like:
Patient ID, Patient Name, Date of sales order 1, date of sales order 2, null (when there aren't any more matches).

I have read all I can find on VLOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH and can't seem to find a function that works where there are multiple matches on the second sheet (the patient ID would be the same over and over for every sales order on sheet 2).

Please help.

Comment: This seems more of a database application than a spreadsheet. That said, I think you can do it with work cells (maybe on a separate work sheet). Each work cell would add to the previous cell the result of a `MATCH()` from one past the result in the previous cell, using `INDIRECT()` or `ADDRESS()` to specify the cell range. The same functions would then be used to address the data that you want to extract from the matched row. This is all rather complex, and I don't have time to work out the details and create data for testing, but I hope this note points to a possible solution.

Comment: Rather than finding results with a formula, you could set up filter criteria and then autofilter sheet 2 with those criteria. I've set up something like this with 2 comboboxes (drop downs) and a "search" button. The comboboxes populate based on ranges in sheet 2. This requires a bit of VBA though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't require any helper columns or sorting of any of the tables. It just uses one relatively simple array formula.

Set up the two worksheets like the following, with the second sheet named `Sheet2`:

[image: Worksheet 1 Screenshot]

[image: Worksheet 2 Screenshot]

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in cell `C3` of the first sheet and copy-paste/fill-down into `C3:G7`:

```dart
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IFERROR(1/(1/((Sheet2!$A$2:$A$20=$A3)*(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$20))),""),C$2),"")}
```

Be aware that if the last Date cell of the Patients table in Sheet 1 is filled, there *may* be  more dates that aren't showing. In the example worksheet, I have added a formula in the column to the right of the table to warn if this is the case:

That formula, array entered in `H3` and copy-pasted/filled-down into `H3:H7`, is:

```dart
{=IF(ISERROR(SMALL(IFERROR(1/(1/((Sheet2!$A$2:$A$20=$A3)*(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$20))),""),G$2+1)),"","more")}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by counting the orders per customer. There are many variations on how you can use to solve this, but here is one.

**Step 1:**

Sort your orders table with the newest orders first.

**Step 2:**

Add a column at the end of your sales orders with a formula that counts the customer numbers. In the new column, second row, write the formula `=Countif(B$2:B2,B2)`.

Copy the formula down.

`B` is the column where the customer numbers are found.

**Step 3:**

Add a column with a unique key to identify customer number and order count. 
In the second new column, second row write formula `=B2&" "&X2`

`B` is the customer number and `X` is the order count you made in step 2.

**Step 4:**

In your patients table, add a column that index-matches the ID for the newest order, the second newest order, etc. to return the date. Use an `IFERROR()` to return A blank if there is no match, and use absolute references so the formulas can be easily copied:

(I tried to translate the formula from my Norwegian Excel)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Order list'!$C:$C,MATCH('Patient list'!$A2&" "&'Patient list'!B$1,'Order list'!$Y:$Y,0)),"")
```

where `C` is the column with dates and `Y` is where the key in step 3 is.

I hope this can set you on the right path to find a tailored solution for your tables. You can probably automate the formulas in the order table etc.

Orders:

[image: Screenshot of Orders Table]

Patients:

[image: Screenshot of Patients Table]